# Ngnix Docker not serving content

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to build a docker container out of an angular 4 application. When running it with

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /Users/mles/Documents/devicelab/dist/devicelab:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

I can see the index.html in the browser with localhost:80.

To make it portable I've made a DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM nginx

COPY dist/devicelab /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I'm building it with

```
docker build --no-cache --rm -t dockerregistry.test.com/devicelab/devicelab .
```

then running it with

```
docker run dockerregistry.test.com/devicelab/devicelab:latest
```

Now when I hit localhost:80 nothing is happening. Nothin shows up in the browser and there is no log on the console. What is wrong with my Dockerfile?

Comment: Which OS do you use? if its a docker daemon that is running on a VM you might have an address other then localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the port on `docker run`

`docker run -p 80:80 dockerregistry.test.com/devicelab/devicelab:latest`

Answer (score 2):

@rafaelncarvalho was correct in regards to the `-p` param, but for clarification the `-p` is to *publish* the already exposed port to the outside the network. Without the `-p` nginx will be accessible if you `exec -it bash` in, but not outside. The `-p` aka `--publish` also allows gives you control for mapping the container port to what you choose. ex `docker container run -p 8080:80 nginx` will publish the nginx server on port `8080`